# Gravity prerender taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to prepopulate a category field or post drop down in gravity forms.  Here is what I have:

```
<?php

add_filter("gform_pre_render", "gform_prepopluate_populate_books");

//Note: when changing drop down values, we also need to use the gform_admin_pre_render so that the right values are displayed when editing the entry.
add_filter("gform_admin_pre_render", "gform_prepopluate_populate_books");

function gform_prepopluate_populate_books($form){
    $posttype = 'books';
    $taxtype = 'genres';
    $formid = 5;
    $fieldid = 14);

    //only populating drop down for form id 5
    if($form["id"] != $formid)
       return $form;

    //Reading posts for "Business" category;
    //$posts = query_posts(array('post_type' => array('post', 'movies')));
   // $posts = query_posts( array( 'post_type' => $querytype ) );


    $taxonomies=get_taxonomies(array('name' => $taxtype ), 'names'); 
   // if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    //Creating drop down item array.
    $items = array();

    //Adding initial blank value.
    $items[] = array("text" => "", "value" => "");

    //Adding post titles to the items array
    if ( $taxonomies ) {
        foreach($taxonomies  as $taxonomy) {
            $items[] = array("value" => $taxonomy->slug, "text" => $taxonomy->name);
        }
    }

    //Adding items to field id 8. Replace 8 with your actual field id. You can get the field id by looking at the input name in the markup.
    foreach($form["fields"] as &$field)
        if($field["id"] == $fieldid ) {            
            $field["choices"] = $items;
    }

}
```

Doesn't seem to be working to populate my taxonomy values into my dropdown.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Wordpress experts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoured the web and modified a snippet, in case anybody is interested:

```
<?php

add_filter("gform_pre_render", "gform_prepopluate_populate_books");
add_filter("gform_admin_pre_render", "gform_prepopluate_populate_books");

function gform_prepopluate_populate_books($form){

    //Grab all Terms Associated with a Specific Taxonomy;
    global $post;
    $taxonomy = 'genres';
    $formid = 5;
    $fieldid = 14;

    if($form["id"] != $formid)
        return $form;
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'hide_empty=0&orderby=none');

    //Creating drop down item array.
    $items = array();

    //Adding initial blank value.
    $items[] = array("text" => "", "value" => "");

    //Adding term names to the items array
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $is_selected = $term->name == "testing" ? true : false;
        $items[] = array("value" => $term->name, "text" => $term->name, "isSelected"=> $is_selected);
    }

    //Adding items to field id 1. Replace 1 with your actual field id. You can get the field id by looking at the input name in the markup.
    foreach($form["fields"] as &$field)
        if($field["id"] == $fieldid){
            $field["type"] = "select";
            $field["choices"] = $items;
        }

    return $form;
}
```